# webcam recording with red5

Tags: webcam, red5, recording, video-recording

We have a red5 recorder/red5 server setup. This is working correctly and videos are getting created in the server. We are having a problem with the recording and playback etc not working in a streamlined way. ie after you record and play the recorded one, it may not always play. The player sort of gets stuck.

Are there any free or paid alternatives to red5 recorder that does the job really well?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the videos don't play can vary and it is not sure if another streaming server will resolve your issue. For example if you have network issues no matter what streaming server you use, it will fail.
However, alternatives might be Wowza or Adobe FMS.

Sebastian

Comment: No im not going for another server. The red5-recorder flash application seems to be broken. I would like to use red5 server with some flash based recording application. This is being tested locally so that rules out network issues.

Comment: without knowing your recording and playback code there is no chance you will get an exact answer. Also "does not play" ... is there any error thrown in the Flash interface? It sounds like you produce a ActionScript error in the client side. That is why nothing works anymore in the UI.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/red5-recorder/downloads/list
This is the recorder that we use. And the latest red5 server. I don't think we have done anything custom.

Comment: the app you are refering to is from  Aug 2008. This application certainly will NOT work anymore with latest Red5 server. You have plenty of exceptions in the log. You just need to read it ;)

Comment: The whole point of starting this thread was to get a alternative for the recording application which will work with red5 server :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are suffering from the same problem I have, see:
[WARN o.r.s.net.rtmpt.BaseRTMPTConnection - Response buffer was null after encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477466/warn-o-r-s-net-rtmpt-basertmptconnection-response-buffer-was-null-after-encodi)

Are there any warnings in your log file after the stream did fail? This log file may reveal your problem, see /usr/local/red5/log/red5.log

Comment: The log does not have any errors. I guess the recorder flash application is broken